# sort numbers and get the rank in c#

Tags: c#, sorting, ranking

How can we sort a `double[]` array in `c#` and get the ranks.
For instance consider sorting

```
[4 5 3 1 6]
```

in descending order.

I want to map each element to its index in the sorted list. For example, if I sort the list I'll get [6 5 4 3 2 1], so 6's index is 1, 5's index is 2 and so on.  The desired output would be:

```
[3     2     4     5     1]
```

I searched a lot but found nothing

Comment: 1. See the overload of LINQ's `.Select()` with index and create anonymous object that consists of data and index 2. Order by data 3. Select index

Comment: I don't understand. Assume I have defined an array like this:
double[] sina = new double[5];
sina[0] = 5;
sina[1] = 4;
sina[2] = 7;
sina[3] = 9;
sina[4] = 1;
you mean use sina.Select(3)? but that gives error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using Linq:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         var ints = new[] { 4, 5, 3, 1, 6 };
         foreach (var item in ints.Select((x, i)=>new { OldIndex = i, Value = x, NewIndex = -1})
                                  .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Value)
                                  .Select((x, i) => new { OldIndex = x.OldIndex, Value = x.Value, NewIndex = i + 1})
                                  .OrderBy(x=>x.OldIndex))
             Console.Write(item.NewIndex + " ");

    }
```

Comment: that did the trick. thanks. But I still dont understand why do things like this should be so complicated in c#.

Comment: It's not *that* complicated. What language makes it easier?

Comment: I used to do this in matlab with a simple code [a,b]=sort(array,'descend')

Comment: In Matlab the sort operation outputs the grading (set of indices that would convert a vector to a sorted vector, 5 2 1 3 4), not the ranking (for each element provide its index in the sorted list, 3 2 4 5 1). If you want the ranking you need to grade twice (in opposite directions if grading down as your original question is asking). In Linq, grading operations require a Select and an OrderBy, and ranking operations require two of each. Since the grading direction is down, you end up with one OrderBy and one OrderByDescending.